The woman in the flashback in Ark: The Animated Series (Ark Survival Evolved), who was she?
The flashbacks were about Helen Walker (the 21 Century Australian woman who wrote the Dossiers in-game) in her life on Earth. She was seen with a blue-haired woman and the two were reallly good friends. The flashbacks involved some police officers arriving at her doorstep to tell her bad news. She falls to her knees crying, and later is shown mixing pills with wine and we see her hand falling limp. And that’s the last we see of her life on Earth before waking up on the Island.
Who was that friend of Helena’s, and what was the bad news the officers told her?

Wasn't the latter part explained in their dialogue?

As in, something bad happened to the woman?

The woman is Victoria Walker (voiced by the actor Elliot Page), and she is Helena's wife, so one could say that they are very good friends.
At some point, she was doing humanitarian work in a region of China where there was an armed conflict of some sort, and she disappeared. As I recall the dialogue from the officers, they did not say anything to indicate that her death had been definitively confirmed, so it is entirely possible that she could, for instance, show up on the Ark in the second half of the first season, or be waiting for Helena if she returns, but as far as Helena and the viewers know, she is presumed dead.
This was the inciting incident that caused Helena to become depressed and attempt (or actually commit?) suicide, which is the "mixing pills with wine" mentioned in the question, and which presumably has something to do with how she ended up on the Ark, since all the rest of them seem to have been taken right when they were about to die.
